# Having trouble media play I developed in Java

Tags: java, media-player

I developed and ran this Code in the Java IDE Eclipse.Here is the code that I developed for the Main class:

```
package application;

import com.sun.prism.paint.Color;



import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Player player=new Player("file:///C:/getg.mp4");
    Scene scene=new Scene(player, 750, 480);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();




}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

And here is the code I developed for the Player class:
package application;

```
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;

public class Player extends BorderPane {    
    Media media;
    MediaPlayer player;
    MediaView view;
    Pane mpane;
    public Player(String file){
        media=new Media(file);
        player=new MediaPlayer(media);
        view =new MediaView(player);
        mpane=new Pane();

        mpane.getChildren().add(view);
        setCenter(mpane);

        player.play();


    }

}
```

And here is the error that I generate:

```
Exception in Application start method  
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1323468230.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\getg.mp4 (The system cannot find the file specified)
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Unknown Source)
at application.Player.<init>(Player.java:16)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:17)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/260348613.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/573945332.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
 Exception running application application.Main
```

I installed Java Effects , what do you think is wrong?

Comment: `Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : C:\getg.mp4 (The system cannot find the file specified)
` - What do you need more?

Comment: I actually thought that file would be created when I wrote the code for media player.

Comment: I don't know how you came to that assumption? What did you expect the contents to be? It's not a media **recorder**, right? So you need to get an example file somewhere.

Comment: First google hit was this: http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5

Comment: Alright I added a random video file I saved on my desktop and changed the line of code to "Player player=new Player("file:///C:/Users/Courtney/Desktop/Field Equations.mp4");" And I still get an error:

"Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 39: file:///C:/Users/Courtney/Desktop/Field Equations.mp4
 at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
 ... 1

Comment: :) You really need to actually read those messages. "Illegal character in path at index 39" ... That is: "file:///C:/Users/Courtney/Desktop/Field Equations.mp4" Index starts at 0 , so 39 is ... the space in "Field Equations" ... For a start you can replace it by underscore and accordingly rename the file ... you can deal with illegal characters in filenames later.

Comment: Thanks , that work silly me